# NoSuchMethodError in google maps api android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am encountering frequent crashes of my app on devices running Android 2.3.x lately. They all boil down to the following stacktrace with the Google Maps API.
My app requires a minimum SDK version of 10 and includes the compat libraries v3 and v7 (via a library project). Interestingly enough it actually works on my test device running Android 2.3.6 so it does not crash on all old devices. On all newer Androids it works of course without a problem.
To my understanding this should not crash because the compat library adds this specific method `requestSendAccessibilityEvent` which has been added in API level 14.

**STACK_TRACE**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.ViewParent.requestSendAccessibilityEvent
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.bc.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ai.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ax.f(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.do.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have raised this with the Dev team and include it here as a cross-reference:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7230

Comment: Show some code atleast.

Comment: As the google code is obfuscated I don't know where the crash is happening. I think it makes little sense to post my whole activity ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I can see this happening here on some apps. Very few users have this crash, but its visible. I assume that google-api changed and they *****-up something. Lets wait 6 more weeks and test again (the time it takes them to deliver new APIs to phones).

Programming for Android is ... interesting... as your app depends on Google-APIs and they change in the lifecyle of your app, this means that your app gets modified by google without you knowing it.